# Internationalization of Button Images

Tags: xcode, localization, internationalization

I've built an iPhone App, but I would like to make it supporting two languages (EN & FR), but in a specific way: because my app displays text in "pictured buttons" and not "text in label".

If the localization is France, I want the app to display the french buttons I've drawn on photoshop. And, if ever the localization is everything else than French, I want the app to display the english buttons I've prepared.

May you redirect me to a simple and easy tutorial, or simply tell me what lines of code I've to write, and where.

Answer (score 0):

If you select the image in the left-hand project navigator pane, then go to the right-hand file inspector pane, you will see a list of localisations.  You can add English or French there.  You will see a disclosure arrow to the side of the image in the project navigator now.  You can open it to see the different versions, and you can right-click to show them in Finder.  Your localised files will be present in your project directory under `en.lproj` and `fr.lproj` directories and you can edit them at will.

To make sure that English is the default, go to your target's info pane and set your localisation native development region to `en`.

If you have already run the project, it will have already installed a non-localised set of your images on your device/simulator.  You'll have to delete the app before running it again, otherwise your application will probably pick up the non-localised version of the images.